# Experimental method for measuring electric dipole momentum of electron

Tags: standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, elementary-particles

Is there any experiment for finding the electric dipole momentum of electron?
Provided that, The Standard Model predicted EDM for leptons including electrons.

Comment: [This experiment](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.11841) is one attempt to measure it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, experiments for measuring the electron EDM are performed since the 1960s. For now, only lower bounds were established. The lowest bound measured so far is |de| < 4.1 × 10−30 ecm (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.11841.pdf)